# Configuring two half-separate lans using DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have to set up DHCP that has to assign IPs over 2 networks (192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24). That is easy and I've got it working.

The question is, is it possible to make PCs from one network accessible to PCs on the other network without allowing the opposite?  (First network should not be accessible from the second).

That's what my teacher has asked me to do and I'm not even sure whether it is possible (eg. pinging from first network against second network works, but vice versa will not).

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score -1):

Think about the fact that you just accessed this page from a computer on your network.  The www.askubuntu.com server however can not access the files on your computer.

So yes, it is possible.